# How to use storage_path() to view an image in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using `storage_path()` for storing uploaded images, but when I use it is pointing wrong on my page.

I use it like this `{{ $data->thumbnail }}` where `$data` came from the database and thumbnail comes as the string which used `storage_path`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us take a look at the default L4 application structure:

app            // contains restricted server-side application data

app/storage    // a writeable directory used by L4 and custom functions to store data ( i.e. log files, ... )

public         // this directory is accessible for clients

If I were you, I would upload the file to the public directory directly:

1. Store image here: public_path() . 'img/filename.jpg'
2. Save the 'img/filename.jpg' in database
3. Generate the image URL with url('img/filename.jpg') => http://www.your-domain.com/img/filename.jpg

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

The storage_path function returns the path to the storage folder, which is inside the app folder --and outside the public folder-- so it's not directly accessible from the client, that's why your images are not being displayed. You can move them to the public folder path, or you could use a custom controller to handle the image requests, read the image from the storage folder and return the value.