# How to get file URL using Storage facade in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, flysystem

I've been experimenting using the new Flysystem integration with Laravel 5.  I am storing 'localised' paths to the DB, and getting the Storage facade to complete the path. For example I store `screenshots/1.jpg` and using

```
Storage::disk('local')->get('screenshots/1.jpg')
```

or

```
Storage::disk('s3')->get('screenshots/1.jpg')
```

I can retrieve the same file on different disks.

`get` retrieves the file contents, but I am hoping to use it in my views like this:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::path('screenshots/1.jpg') }}" />
```

but path, or anything able to retrieve the full path is not available (as far as I can see).  So how can I return the full path?  Or, I'm wondering if this is by design?  If so, why am I not supposed to be able to get the full path?  Or, am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: You are asking for the url and not the path.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Edit: Solution for L5.2+**

There's a better and more straightforward solution.

Use `Storage::url($filename)` to get the full path/URL of a given file. Note that you need to set `S3` as your storage filesystem in `config/filesystems.php`: `'default' => 's3'`

Of course, you can also do `Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename)` in the same way.

As you can see in `config/filesystems.php` there's also a parameter `'cloud' => 's3'` defined, that refers to the Cloud filesystem. In case you want to mantain the storage folder in the local server but retrieve/store some files in the cloud use `Storage::cloud()`, which also has the same filesystem methods, i.e. `Storage::cloud()->url($filename)`.

The Laravel documentation doesn't mention this method, but if you want to know more about it you can check its source code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L231).

Comment: nice! this is a [new method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/ef81c531512de75214e3723fa0725c2b64ad6395#diff-897d962b3751fa634c9cef12e32e7318), but I'm glad it's here now! Does the Storage class work in views by default? If so, will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: yes! it works in your views by default, so you don't have to worry about it at all.

Comment: **This is for L5.2+**

Answer (score 159):

The Path to your Storage disk would be :

```
$storagePath  = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix()
```

I don't know any shorter solutions to that...

You could share the $storagePath to your Views and then just call

```
$storagePath."/myImg.jpg";
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution to get the path of the public storage folder. Thanks!

Comment: Another way is to use `applyPathPrefix` like this: `Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix('myImg.jpg');`

Comment: Thanks for the two ways!

Comment: @maximLanin: Somehow if you copy your example, the last (applyPathPrefix) has an weird character between the h and P (path*Prefix). If you copy paste that, you will get an error. The first `applyPathPrefix` you can copy. Very strange. (you can test it by double clicking the last method name in your example.

Comment: `getDriver()` is not needed. Simply `Storage::disk('local')->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix()` will work as well.

Comment: Perhaps good to know that since Laravel 5.4 there is a new, simple method `Storage::path`, see [Bilal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49532280/2286722)

Answer (score 86):

This method exists since Laravel 5.4, you can get it by:

```
$path = Storage::disk('public')->path($filename);
```

Answer (score 8):

This is how I got it to work - switching between s3 and local directory paths with an environment variable, passing the path to all views.

In .env:

```
APP_FILESYSTEM=local or s3
S3_BUCKET=BucketID
```

In config/filesystems.php:

```
'default' => env('APP_FILESYSTEM'),
```

In `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider`:

```php
public function boot()
{
    view()->share('dynamic_storage', $this->storagePath());
}

protected function storagePath()
{
    if (Storage::getDefaultDriver() == 's3') {
        return Storage::getDriver()
                ->getAdapter()
                ->getClient()
                ->getObjectUrl(env('S3_BUCKET'), '');
    }

    return URL::to('/');
}
```

Comment: Using the s3 Storage as describe generated an error for me. So I amended the example to this

`return Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient()->getObjectUrl(env('S3_BUCKET'), '').'/'; `

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to display storage (disk) path use this:

```
Storage::disk('local')->url('screenshots/1.jpg'); // storage/screenshots/1.jpg
Storage::disk('local')->url(''): // storage
```

Also, if you are interested, I created a package (https://github.com/fsasvari/laravel-uploadify) just for Laravel so you can use all those fields on Eloquent model fields:

```
$car = Car::first();

$car->upload_cover_image->url();
$car->upload_cover_image->name();
$car->upload_cover_image->basename();
$car->upload_cover_image->extension();
$car->upload_cover_image->filesize();
```

Answer (score 5):

First get file url/link then path, as below:

```
$url = Storage::disk('public')->url($filename);
$path = public_path($url);
```

Comment: $url = Storage::disk('public')->url($filename);
works for me in Laravel 10

Answer (score 4):

If you need absolute URL of the file, use below code:

```
$file_path = \Storage::url($filename);
$url = asset($file_path);
// Output: http://example.com/storage/filename.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, weeks ago I made a very similiar question ([Get CDN url from uploaded file via Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442411/get-cdn-url-from-uploaded-file-via-storage)): I wanted the CDN url to show the image in my view (as you are requiring ).

However, after review the package API I confirmed that there is no way do this task. So, my solution was avoid using `flysystem`. In my case, I needed to play with RackSpace. So, finally decide to create my use package and make my own storage package using [The PHP SDK for OpenStack](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud).

By this way, you have full access for functions that you need like `getPublicUrl()` in order to get the public URL from a cdn container:

```
/** @var DataObject $file */
$file = \OpenCloud::container('cdn')->getObject('screenshots/1.jpg');

// $url:  https://d224d291-8316ade.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/screenshots/1.jpg
$url = (string) $file->getPublicUrl(UrlType::SSL);
```

In conclusion, if need to take storage service to another level, then `flysystem` is not enough. For `local` purposes, you can try @nXu's solution

Answer (score 3):

this work for me in 2020 at laravel 7

```
        $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $image_resize->resize(800,600);
        $image_resize->save(Storage::disk('episodes')->path('') . $imgname);
```

so you can use it like this

```
echo Storage::disk('public')->path('');
```

Comment: working with Laravel 5.6 as well.
 `$url = Storage::disk('public')->path('filename.json');
        $cities = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); `

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I found is this:

```
Storage::disk('documents')->getDriver()->getConfig()->get('url')
```

Will return the url with the base path of the documents Storage

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [How to use storage_path() to view an image in laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029121/how-to-use-storage-path-to-view-an-image-in-laravel-4) . The same applies to Laravel 5:

Storage is for the file system, and the most part of it is not accessible to the web server. The recommended solution is to store the images somewhere in the public folder (which is the document root), in the `public/screenshots/` for example. 
Then when you want to display them, use `asset('screenshots/1.jpg')`.

Comment: I am trying to set up a 'disk' to be my public folder when developing and s3 when live

Comment: It doesn't really matter, `Storage::path()` returns the path of the file on your server, but you need a URL to it and the webserver can only serve files from your document root, which is `<project>/public`. Create your directories inside it and use `url()` or `asset()` in the blade templates.

Comment: `Storage::path()` doesn't exist, I'd like it to though

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood, sorry. What I'd do, is still the same: save the full path to the DB, be it local or s3. When uploading / creating images, simply check for `getenv('debug')` and decide which one to use.

Comment: I was trying to avoid saving the full path but maybe it is the most sensible way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i made separate method for local files, in this file:
src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php

```
    /**
 * Get the local path for the given filename.
 * @param $path
 * @return string
 */
public function localPath($path)
{
    $adapter = $this->driver->getAdapter();
    if ($adapter instanceof LocalAdapter) {
        return $adapter->getPathPrefix().$path;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException('This driver does not support retrieving local path');
    }
}
```

then, i create pull request to framework, but it still not merged into main core yet:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13605
May be someone merge this one))