# Get first row of csv file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to ask how can I get the first row (the column names) in laravel?
For now I load my file from storage.
I have tried $contents[0]; but it did not work.

```
public function csvread(Request $request) {
$contents = Storage::disk('public')->get('asdf.csv');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Something wrong with [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv)?

Comment: Have you ascertained if the call you are making is successful? Try dumping the value of `$contents` to make sure you are getting an expected value. I am not familiar with Laravel but I speculate it either returns some sort of file object, or `false` if not successful... Or, are you getting an error message? If so you should add it to the question for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Laravel so I cannot comment specifically on the functionality of `Storage`. However, I had a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem), which states the following:

> The get method may be used to retrieve the contents of a given file. The raw string contents of the file will be returned by the method

So, assuming the call you made successfully found and read a file, `$contents` is a string - and dereferencing `$contents[0]` is just going to return the first character of the string. Not what you want, clearly!

I concur wth @JonStirling in the question comments and try to parse the csv directly with [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). Or, if you want to be more object-based you could use [`SplFileObject()`](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fgetcsv.php) which can read and iterate over CSV files, given the appropriate flags.

Here's a copy of example #2 from the PHP docs:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("animals.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
foreach ($file as $row) {
    list($animal, $class, $legs) = $row;
    printf("A %s is a %s with %d legs\n", $animal, $class, $legs);
}
```

You'll need the orignal filepath to pass to `SplFileObject()` too of course - [this answer should be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430611/312962)

Finally, if your CSV has empty lines, you might have to add additional flags to `SplFileObject` - namely `SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY` and `SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD`

You may also opt to use a pre-existing package; e.g: http://csv.thephpleague.com/

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I had some problems with getting url of my file, even with your link to question about it. But finally I've solved it. Your answer is very exhaustive.

Comment: Hey, I have one more question is there any posibility to check if one of the columns is named 'name' or 'surname' ?

Comment: Hi. Just saw this. It depends on your data but assuming your the first line of your csv contains a "header" row, you could check that the first row contains "surname" with `in_array()`?