# Laravel download not working

Tags: laravel, download

In my application I have the need to:

1. upload a file
2. store information in the db
3. store the file in a local or remote filesystem
4. listing all the db rows with a link to download the file
5. remove the file from the db and from the filesystem

I am trying to develop the 4th but the solutions found [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/response-download-with-file-from-storage?page=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964412/how-to-get-file-path-using-storage-facade-in-laravel-5) don't work for me.

My **filesystem.php** is:

```
'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'myftpsite' => [
        'driver'   => 'ftp',
        'host'     => 'myhost',
        'username' => 'ftpuser,
        'password' => 'ftppwd',

        // Optional FTP Settings...
        // 'port'     => 21,
         'root'     => '/WRK/FILE/TEST',
        // 'passive'  => true,
        // 'ssl'      => true,
        // 'timeout'  => 30,
    ],
```

In the `Controller` I store the file with:

```
    ... validation here ...
    $path = $request->uploadfile->storeAs('', $request->uploadfile->getClientOriginalName(), self::STORAGEDISK);
    $file = new TESTFile;
    ... db code here ...
    $file->save();
```

At this point I would like to retrive the variable to pass to the download methods (url or path of my file). I found 2 ways

- `Storage::url($pspfile->filename) *return* **/storage/** accept.png`
- `Storage::disk(self::STORAGEDISK)->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix($pspfile->filename) *return* C:\xampp\htdocs\myLaravel\ **storage** \app\accept.png`

Any help or suggestion to do it in a better way will be very appreciated.

**EDIT**
For the moment I separete local/public from FTP.
The download is working if in the `Controller` I modify

```
$path = $request->uploadfile->storeAs('',
          $request->uploadfile->getClientOriginalName()
          ,self::STORAGEDISK);
$file->fullpath = $path;
```

with

```
$file->fullpath = storage_path('app\\') . $path;
```

where **'app\'** is the **storage_path** configured as **root** in *filesystem.php* 
Moreover I can avoid to hardcode and use

`$file->fullpath = Storage::disk(self::STORAGEDISK)
                           ->getDriver()
                           ->getAdapter()
                           ->getPathPrefix() . $path;`

In this way the download method can use

```
return response()->download($pspfile->fullpath);
```

I am still looking for a way to retrive a valid **scr** attribute for an *img* tag.

In addition I would like the same with remote stored files (maybe with local temp dir and file?)

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar some time ago. Maybe this example code helps you.

```
class FileController extends Controller
{
    // ... other functions ...

    public function download(File $file)
    {
        if (Storage::disk('public')->exists($file->path)) {
            return response()->download(public_path('storage/' . $file->path), $file->name);
        } else {
            return back();
        }
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'file-upload' => 'required|file',
        ]);

        $path = request()->file('file-upload')->store('uploads', 'public');
        $file = new File;
        $file->name = request()->file('file-upload')->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->path = $path;
        $file->save();

        return back();
    }
}
```

Comment: **upload** instead of using store I use storeAs. Instead of **public** i switch (just for basic testing) from local to FTP. As you can see I leave blank the _directory name_ in order to store in remote dir configured in filesystem.php or for local disk in storing file in storage/app. In both ways the file is stored as expected. The path stored in the db is the same as the file name. Also the _get_ methods of _Storage_ facade works but I don't understand if I need it to download or if I need only path () and If the same path can be used as src attrib in img tag.