# How to display pdf in browser?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to show pdf online in the user browser, but I couldn't make it works.

My controller :

```
public function showJournal($file) {
        $filepath = Storage::disk('jurnal')->get($file);

        return (new Response($filepath, 200))
                        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    }
```

The route :

```
Route::get('view_journal/{file}', 'JournalController@showJournal')->name('showjurnal');
```

The view :

```
<iframe src="{{route('showjurnal', $journal->file)}}" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;min-height:640px;"></iframe>
```

The codes above doesn't work as it always returning error `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`.  The file is stored in `public/jurnal`. How do I solve this error ? thanks

Comment: If you give correct file path then you can display file using get to obtain file path from request

Comment: `NotFoundHttpException` is for invalid route which doesn't exists in route file `web.php` so please check route exist there or not

Comment: I store the file in `public/jurnal/text.pdf`. How do I retrieve the correct path ? @SagarGautam

Comment: I think you have stored filename in database so you can use `asset($filepath)` to get correct path of the file. `asset() ` provides path up to `public/` directory. So , you can try `src="{{asset('/jurnal/text.pdf')}}"` it should work

Comment: Yes it works but will force-download the file instead of opening it. @SagarGautam

Comment: You are returning response that's the reason for force-download so just return filepath as variable then display using `<embed>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [file responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#file-responses) available from laravel 5.2 and above

```
return response()->file($pathToFile);
```

Comment: check file in the `$filepath` is readable and also check the path is correct

Comment: I store the file in `public/jurnal/text.pdf`. How do I retrieve the correct path ?

Comment: try this `Storage::url($filename)` File name is `jurnal/text.pdf` 

or set public/jurnal as the default path in `config/filesystems.php`

refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964412/how-to-get-file-path-using-storage-facade-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

Store the file not in the public folder, if you want to use Storage. Store the file under storage/app/jurnal/text.pdf for the default Storage Driver. And then you can get the file with

`return response()->download( Storage::getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix("jurnal/text.pdf")`;

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
<iframe src="{{route('showjurnal', $journal->file)}}" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;min-height:640px;"></iframe>
```

To

```
<iframe src="{{ url(Storage::disk('jurnal')->url($journal->file)) }}" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;min-height:640px;"></iframe>
```