# Laravel - Can't save file from Disk to database record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, octobercms

I'm using S3 to store my files. I have a video saved in my directory. I want to take the video from S3 and save it to a record in my DB. This is the code I'm using:

```
$file = Storage::get('input/TESTING.mp4');
            
$newer->video = $file;
```

I'm getting this error (which comes from the second line of my code):

```
file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given
```

The file does exist, I'm 100% sure, Laravel is finding it. I used the Storage::exists() function to test that.

I'm not sure what the problem is, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the code actually throwing the error? How is the second line throwing the error? What happens in the `$newer` object? What you get from Storage is an S3 link, not necessarily a path. You can check by dumping the $file variable

Answer (score 0):

The method `Storage::get` returns the content of the file and not the location. You can see it on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#retrieving-files).

To get the path, you should do something like that:

```
$path = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix('filename.png');
```

Or, since Laravel 5.4:

```
$path = Storage::disk('public')->path('filename.png');
```

More details:

[How to get file URL using Storage facade in laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964412/how-to-get-file-url-using-storage-facade-in-laravel-5)